# Mysql error #1064 in Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a problem when I upload mysql from localhost to my server. The error message show like below.

Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 76)
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `actions` ( `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT )

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQTtK.png)

Please help me. how to fix this error....

Answer (score 0):

I just try many ways to solve mysql error. Fortunately, I found the ways to fix it. Just update phpmyadmin version in localhost to be the same at server version.
Then, it's worked for me.
Hope this way help you to solve your error when you get the same at me.